# Is there any pre-commit hook in Team Foundation Server 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'd like to provide a sort of UI on a commit operation in Visual Studio for my team. How would I go about that, would I create a Studio add-in or is there a TFS event that would help in this case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Great question!  Unfortunately there isn't an extensibility point on the client side (Visual Studio) to be able to intercept a check-in.  However, there is a server-side extensiblity point (called an ISubscriber Decision Point) that you can intercept and allow/reject the check-in.  Do you think that would be helpful for you?

That extensibility point is not really documented very well but we have some information in Chapter 25 of our new TFS 2010 book ([Wrox Professional Team Foundation Server 2010](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470943327)) about how to create one of these.

Another option would be to create a custom check-in policy... That doesn't seem like the best way to solve the problem though and is riddled with its own issues.

Comment: Yeah, that's the thought we had here too. It's not the best solution, but it's the best one available.

Comment: Great - let us know if you have any questions come up while implementing this particular solution!

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this: every time there is a "check-in", we check if it is the first "check-in" for today, if it is, then we upgrade the version number. Thanks.